# Not receiving UDP message on local machine

Tags: python, c#, sockets, networking, udp

So I have two machines, a laptop and a raspberry pi 4. I am trying to send UDP packets to the pi from my laptop.

C# code running on laptop:

```cs
            public static void SendMessage(string msg, IPEndPoint endPoint)
            {
                using (UdpClient client = new())
                {
                    var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                    client.Send(message, message.Length, endPoint);
                }
            }
```

which I am calling in Main():

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(()=>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                        Networking.UDP.SendMessage("Hello World!", new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse($"192.168.1.{i}"), 11000));
                    Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }).Start();
        }
```

On the raspberry pi I am running this simple python script:

```py
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()

local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
local_port = 11000

UDPsocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPsocket.bind((local_ip, local_port))

print("Now listening on port "+str(local_port))

while (True):
    bytesAddressPair = UDPsocket.recvfrom(1024)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]
    print(str(address)+" : "+str(message))
```

However, the raspberry pi program does not seem to receive any messages. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain there are no firewalls in the way?

Comment: On receiver side check that "local_ip" isn't "127.0.0.1" or just use "0.0.0.0" to bind to all interfaces (but this may be less secure).

Comment: @canton7 I did not think about that, how would I go about disabling or limiting any firewalls?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I got the ip from the pi through the hostname -I command

Comment: @AlexKaff, Michael's point is, make sure that the **variable** `local_ip` in your Python script does not contain `127.0.0.1`. Make sure that it contains the `192.168.1.x` IP address of the Pi

Comment: Searching around, it seems that Raspberry Pi OS doesn't enable a firewall by default

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: First comment on this answer explains the reason)

Figured it out.
On the pi, in order to get the local IP I was using

```py
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

which apparently was not the correct way to get the local IP. Someone might be able to further explain why that was not producing the correct outcome.
To solve the issue I just ran `hostname -I` on the pi to find the correct local IP and used that in the code, with the final receiving code being:

```py
import socket

local_ip = "192.168.1.10" #Your local IP here obtained from terminal
local_port = 11000

UDPsocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPsocket.bind((local_ip, local_port))

print("Now listening on port "+str(local_port))

while (True):
    bytesAddressPair = UDPsocket.recvfrom(1024)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]

    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    print(str(address)+" : "+str(message))
```

Comment: Again, as we said in the comments, please check to see what `ocket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` returns! If it returns `127.0.0.1` then your `UDPsocket.bind` will just be binding to the loopback interface -- it will only listen to packets sent from the same machine, not from other machines. If you just want to listen to packets coming from anywhere, use `0.0.0.0`. If your Pi only has one interface, then `0.0.0.0` and `192.168.1.10` will do the same thing: you only need to use an explicit IP if your PI has multple IPs, and you want to listen on just one of them

Comment: @canton7 that was indeed the issue. If you want you can post that as an answer, else I'll point to your comment at the top of my answer. Thanks